# Div position only in CSS without class

Tags: html, css

I have few `div`s like this:

```html
  <div id=1>
    <div id=2></div>
    <div id=3></div>
    <div id=4>
      <div id=5></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

What I need is set up divs like this:
div 2 is on top left, div 3 is on top right, div 4 is at the bottom right and div5 at the top center of div 4

Problem is that I need to do it only in CSS and without class.

Comment: can u draw a rough sketch of what u want ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use:

```css
#d1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#d2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

#d3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#d4 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

#d5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="d1">
  <div id="d2"></div>
  <div id="d3"></div>
  <div id="d4">
    <div id="d5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I would do that:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #p1 {
      height: 200%;
    }
    
    #p2 {
      background-color: red;
      width: 49%;
      height: 48%;
      position: fixed;
      left: 0%;
      top: 0%;
    }
    
    #p3 {
      background-color: green;
      width: 49%;
      height: 48%;
      position: fixed;
      right: 0%;
      top: 0%;
    }
    
    #p4 {
      background-color: blue;
      width: 100%;
      height: 48%;
      position: fixed;
      right: 0%;
      bottom: 0%;
    }
    
    #p5 {
      position: absolute;
      right: 50%;
      top: 50%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id=p1>
    <div id=p2>2</div>
    <div id=p3>3</div>
    <div id=p4>4
      <div id=p5>5<br>loren ipsum</div>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

This is if you want the div fixed instead if you want div absolute you can try this:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #p1 {
      height: 200%;
    }
    
    #p2 {
      background-color: red;
      width: 49%;
      height: 48%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0%;
      top: 0%;
    }
    
    #p3 {
      background-color: green;
      width: 49%;
      height: 48%;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0%;
      top: 0%;
    }
    
    #p4 {
      background-color: blue;
      width: 100%;
      height: 48%;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0%;
      bottom: 0%;
    }
    
    #p5 {
      position: absolute;
      right: 50%;
      top: 50%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id=p1>
    <div id=p2>2</div>
    <div id=p3>3</div>
    <div id=p4>4
      <div id=p5>5<br>loren ipsum</div>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```